# Forwarding port behind router & voip router

Tags: networking, portforwarding

So I'm trying to host a server. I feel like this should be straight forward but maybe I'm missing something because it's not working. I'm hosting a server that runs on port 7777 and 27015. I've reserved an ip address of ex: 192.168.0.50 in my router settings along with ports forwarded with that address. So my pc is now 192.168.0.50 with both ports added (tcp/udp enabled).

My layout is : pc > router > voip router > modem. Since I have the router finished, I moved on to the voip router. In my voip router I forwarded both ports under my router's gateway 192.168.0.1. Is this correct or should it still be my computer's ip? My voip router does have a WAN ip assigned.

[image]

Am I missing something or did I use the wrong ip for my voip, since my ports still aren't accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check if your modem is a router-modem by checking what is the WAN IP on your voip router (if the WAN IP of the router looks like 192.168.x.x then most likely your modem is acting as a router also and need some configuration done to have the port forward in place. When you have figured this out
make sure you forward the port from your VOIP router to the WAN address on your router. Try testing step by step to figure out where it's failing, First test by connecting a laptop straight into the VOIP router to test if the port forward to your new laptop IP is working good. Then temporarely remove the VOIP router from the equation for a few minute and test with only pc > router > modem to see if port forward works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to figure it out yesterday but what you said pretty much reinforced my learning experience, it was merely a case of me not understanding the addressing of each device. The problem was at the voip router. My voip router had a public wan address (24.212...) so no need for any modem settings. I never realized the voip router also had a LAN ip, that's what I had to use for it to work, I kept using my pc's ip address

Comment: Your welcome. make sure to mark my answer as the solution if it helped you fix your problem.